# How to connect PHP from my laptop to SQL Server 2008 installed in other computer?

Tags: php

I have a problem related to PHP and SQL Server 2008 connection.
I tried to connect PHP and SQL Server in same computer that works fine, but what I exactly needed is to connect PHP file stored in my laptop in C:\xampp\htdocs to SQL server 2008 installed in other computer. So all both my computers are in the same network, when I try to browse php file from in my laptop it say  Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\connection.php on line 12

My connection codes are

```
    <?php
$serverName = "192.168.0.103, 1234"; //serverIP, portNumber
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"school", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"*****");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

How can I solve this the problem?

Please anyone can help me.

Comment: `Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()` you dont have the extension installed on this computer: http://php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.installation.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

both machetes need to be in the same LAN of course

If your edition is SQL Server Express, you should probably be using:

```
$objConnect = mssql_connect("192.168.0.103\SQLEXPRESS","sa","****");
```

Or if it is otherwise a named instance, then

```
$objConnect = mssql_connect("192.168.0.103\InstanceName","sa","****");
```

Of course your firewall must have port 1433 (and possibly 1434) open in order to accept that connection